# Tkinter remove grid label from method

Tags: python, tkinter, methods, widget

I'm writing a simple program with Python and Tkinter.

When clicking on the `ForwardButton` all the widgets shall be removed and then new ones displayed.

This works with the wigets i created first, but the widgets within the `DisplayWelcome` function won't disappear.

Once the first ones (`HelloInfo1`...`SaveName`) are removed.

I get the error:

```
  ... in ForwardButtonClicked
    DisplayWelcome1.grid_remove()
NameError: name 'DisplayWelcome1' is not defined"
```

How can I remove the widgeds called in the method?

```
#DisplayWelcome
def DisplayWelcome():
    DisplayWelcome1 = ttk.Label(root, font=("Calibri", 14), text=(str('Hallo, ' + name.get() + ' :)')))
    DisplayWelcome1.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=tk.NW, padx=0, pady=0)
    DisplayWelcome2 = ttk.Label(root, font=("Calibri", 14), text="xxx")
    DisplayWelcome2.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky=tk.NW, padx=0, pady=0)
    DisplayWelcome3 = ttk.Label(root, font=("Calibri", 14), text="xxx")
    DisplayWelcome3.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky=tk.NW, padx=0, pady=0)
    ForwardButton = ttk.Button(root, text="Weiter", command=lambda: ForwardButtonClicked())
    ForwardButton.grid(column=0, row=8, sticky=tk.NW, padx=0, pady=0)
    getname.delete(0,'end')

#ForwardButtonClicked
def ForwardButtonClicked():
    HelloInfo1.grid_remove()
    HelloInfo2.grid_remove()
    img_label.grid_remove()
    NameInfo.grid_remove()
    getname.grid_remove()
    SaveName.grid_remove()
    DisplayWelcome1.grid_remove()
    DisplayWelcome2.grid_remove()
    DisplayWelcome3.grid_remove()
    ForwardButton.grid_remove()
```

Comment: The problem is `DisplayWelcome1` is local variable only accessible within your `DisplayWelcome()` function. The easiest fix is to declare it with `global DisplayWelcome1` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Just a syntax tip: it is good practice to write function names in `snake_case` and _class_ names in `CamelCase`.